# How to integrate codeIgniter with netbeans fully

Tags: codeigniter, netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-8, netbeans-8.1

I downloaded Netbeans and CodeIgniter, and I downloaded 2 plugins for Netbeans. On of them is called "PHP CI Framework" and I can't install it.

When I try to install it I get this message:

> The plugin php apis is requested in implementation version 201107282000.
>
> The following plugin is effected:
>
> PHP CI Framework

What other plugin do I need to install for CI to be fully integrated so that I will have full Intellisense and documentation support in Netbeans?

Comment: Try this out:
[CodeIgniter plugin for Netbeans](https://github.com/nbphpcouncil/nb-ci-plugin)

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20140221163838/https://alielwafdy.wordpress.com/2012/07/28/codeigniter-support-in-netbeans/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you just want auto-complete of functions then this will do it for you.

1) Create a folder in Netbeans called '*autocomplete*' in '*Source Files*'

2) Create two files in here called something like **ci_code_completion_controllers.php** and **ci_code_completion_models.php**

Add this into each file;

```
<?php
/**
********* CONTROLLERS *********
* @property CI_DB_active_record $db
* @property CI_DB_forge $dbforge
* @property CI_Benchmark $benchmark
* @property CI_Calendar $calendar
* @property CI_Cart $cart
* @property CI_Config $config
* @property CI_Controller $controller
* @property CI_Email $email
* @property CI_Encrypt $encrypt
* @property CI_Exceptions $exceptions
* @property CI_Form_validation $form_validation
* @property CI_Ftp $ftp
* @property CI_Hooks $hooks
* @property CI_Image_lib $image_lib
* @property CI_Input $input
* @property CI_Language $language
* @property CI_Loader $load
* @property CI_Log $log
* @property CI_Model $model
* @property CI_Output $output
* @property CI_Pagination $pagination
* @property CI_Parser $parser
* @property CI_Profiler $profiler
* @property CI_Router $router
* @property CI_Session $session
* @property CI_Security $security
* @property CI_Sha1 $sha1
* @property CI_Table $table
* @property CI_Template $template
* @property CI_Trackback $trackback
* @property CI_Typography $typography
* @property CI_Unit_test $unit_test
* @property CI_Upload $upload
* @property CI_URI $uri
* @property CI_User_agent $agent
* @property CI_Validation $validation
* @property CI_Xmlrpc $xmlrpc
* @property CI_Xmlrpcs $xmlrpcs
* @property CI_Zip $zip
* @property Image_Upload $image_upload
* @property Lang_Detect $lang_detect

********* MODELS *********
* @property User_model $user_model
*/

Class CI_Controller {

}
?>
```

Note: populate the *Models* section with your own.

3) Goto to the *properties* of your project in Netbeans and goto the '*PHP Include Path*' setting.
Add the autocomplete folder to the path.

4) So now in your controllers/model try typing `$this->load->` and hit **Ctrl+spacebar**, you should see a list of avaiable functions.

Comment: I would like to know if this is still the "right way"? Because its been a long time already.

Answer (score 25):

> For NetBeans 8.1+

**Goto:**
https://github.com/nbphpcouncil/nb-ci-plugin/releases

**Download NB CI Plugins (latest release):**

1. org-nbphpcouncil-modules-php-ci-0.5.1.nbm
2. org-nbphpcouncil-modules-php-ci-repository-0.5.1.nbm

**Install Plugins:**
Tools >> Plugins >> Downloaded (tab) >> Add Plugins... >> (browse those downloaded files in your local directory) >> Open >> Install >> Restart NB

**Activate CI Framework:**
Tools >> Options >> PHP >> Frameworks & Tools (tab) >> select CodeIgniter >> Base Files >> Add Zip... >> now type a name and browse for CodeIgniter’s zip file you downloaded >> OK >> OK >> Restart NB

All Done. :)

[image]

**Activate CI framework in existing project:**
Select your project >> Right click >> Properties >> Expand Frameworks >> select CodeIgniter >> tick on Enabled >> OK (Now you'll see a CI logo followed by your project name)

[image]
[image]

Comment: I still not able to go to file by clicking no mouse  $this->load->model('Forms_model'); $this->Forms_model;

Comment: amazing, i am really glad to have this framework working in that way with netbeans

Comment: Thanks, very useful

Comment: Thanks, I had to extract unpack200.exe from openjdk-13.0.2_windows-x64_bin to be able to finish installation on Apache NetBeans IDE 14

Answer (score 2):

hope you are using the version of 7.1.2 better use the 7.1.1 so that you can avoid these kind of error it worked for me or better to use same version plugin for the same IDE of netbeans you are using

Answer (score 0):

I just followed this steps:

1. Download CodeIgniter.3.X.X.zip
2. Unzip the content into the root of your PHP project in Netbeans [file structure with codeIgniter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdkXT.png)
3. Run your project, you will see the Welcome page from CodeIgniter