# How to let the editor know about dynamic properties?

Tags: codeigniter, phpstorm, codeigniter-3, php-ide

The properties are loaded dynamically in CodeIgniter.

How to let the editor know it should be allowed?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It might be useful to mention why you don't want to declare this property, as it may make a difference to the answer. For instance, if you're using `__get` to define _specific_ fields dynamically, there may be ways to declare/document those field names.

Comment: If I declare these properties with `private $form_validation;`, it will instead show a similar error on the method call. `Method 'set_rules' not found in`

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670318/how-to-enable-auto-complete-in-phpstorm-for-codeigniter-framework

Comment: Not a duplicate. Different problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the full list of dynamic properties you're going to use, you can add them as `@property` docblock annotations on the class, in the format `@property type name description`.

The classic use case for this is where the class implements `__get` to lazy-load data, or in your case dependencies injected by the framework.

```
/**
 * @property FormValidation form_validation Form validation object injected by CodeIgniter
 */
class Example {
    public function foo() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('blah', 'blah', 'blah');
    }
}
```

Note that these magic properties are assumed to be inherited, and public, so the following will not show warnings:

```
// Using magic property in child class
class ExampleChild extends Example {
    public function somethingElse() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('something', 'else', 'entirely');
    }
}

// Using magic property from outside class
$foo = new Foo;
$fv = $foo->form_validation;
```