# NetBeans 8.0 PHP CodeIgniter Framework support

Tags: codeigniter, netbeans

I am using **netbeans 8.0** it shows *auto-complete* for *zend* framework but not for *codeigniter*. How can I use it with *codeigniter* for *auto-complete* support???

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to integrate codeIgniter with netbeans fully](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308604/how-to-integrate-codeigniter-with-netbeans-fully)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy the code in the answer here: [Netbeans code completion for CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765908/netbeans-code-completion-for-codeigniter)
into a php file in your project.

I used CI_Autocomplete2.0.php in the root of the project.  It's a hack, but it does work. Since I'm familiarizing myself with CI's syntax & naming conventions it does what I want.

I successfully installed one of the Kenai 7.3 modules in 7.4, but the other one they show on the webpage wasn't listed in the plugin options, so I uninstalled it and now I can't get it to re-install again.  I haven't tried it in my NetBeans 8  yet though.

Edit: Sorry, I just figured out that the Kenai modules were both listed.  The "PHP CI Framework Repository" installed ok (don't know what, if anything, it did yet).  It's the "PHP CI Framework" that won't install and lists out a bunch of module dependencies.  I'll update again if there's anything to add when I try with Nb8.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [Project Kenai](https://kenai.com/projects/nbphpci/pages/Home). Hope that's what you're looking for.

Comment: but in project kenai their is no plugin for netbeans 8.0

Answer (score 0):

use sublime text editor 2 or 3 and install CI:snippets you will get dropdown for the codeigniter or check this link

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/184716/