# CodeIgniter 3.1 and NetBeans 8.0.1 autocompleter

Tags: codeigniter, netbeans

This is my first project with CodeIgniter. I have a problem with autocomplete with Netbeans 8.0.1. I found the answers for this question, but they not working for me.

I Try these solutions but not working for me

[How to integrate codeIgniter with netbeans fully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308604/how-to-integrate-codeigniter-with-netbeans-fully)

[NetBeans 8.0 PHP CodeIgniter Framework support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528784/netbeans-8-0-php-codeigniter-framework-support)

[Netbeans code completion for CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765908/netbeans-code-completion-for-codeigniter)

When I try to add folder to PATH there are following ERROR:

***Shared: Path D:\MyProjects\project\autocomplete is already part of project.***

[image]

**CI_Autocomplete.php**

```
    <?php
    /**
    * @property CI_DB_active_record $db
    * @property CI_DB_forge $dbforge
    * @property CI_Benchmark $benchmark
    * @property CI_Calendar $calendar
    * @property CI_Cart $cart
    * @property CI_Config $config
    * @property CI_Controller $controller
    * @property CI_Email $email
    * @property CI_Encrypt $encrypt
    * @property CI_Exceptions $exceptions
    * @property CI_Form_validation $form_validation
    * @property CI_Ftp $ftp
    * @property CI_Hooks $hooks
    * @property CI_Image_lib $image_lib
    * @property CI_Input $input
    * @property CI_Language $language
    * @property CI_Loader $load
    * @property CI_Log $log
    * @property CI_Model $model
    * @property CI_Output $output
    * @property CI_Pagination $pagination
    * @property CI_Parser $parser
    * @property CI_Profiler $profiler
    * @property CI_Router $router
    * @property CI_Session $session
    * @property CI_Sha1 $sha1
    * @property CI_Table $table
    * @property CI_Trackback $trackback
    * @property CI_Typography $typography
    * @property CI_Unit_test $unit_test
    * @property CI_Upload $upload
    * @property CI_URI $uri
    * @property CI_User_agent $user_agent
    * @property CI_Validation $validation
    * @property CI_Xmlrpc $xmlrpc
    * @property CI_Xmlrpcs $xmlrpcs
    * @property CI_Zip $zip
    */

    class CI_Controller {};

    /**
    * @property CI_DB_active_record $db
    * @property CI_DB_forge $dbforge
    * @property CI_Config $config
    * @property CI_Loader $load
    * @property CI_Session $session
    */

    class CI_Model {};
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow these steps

1. Create `Autocomplete` in **outside of the application folder**.
2. Inside that create `CI_autocomplete.php` file
3. Inside `CI_autocomplete.php` add below code ([Can download here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/o80hj13445vdq5d/CI_Autocomplete.rar))

   ```
   <?php
       /**
       * @property CI_DB_active_record $db
       * @property CI_DB_forge $dbforge
       * @property CI_Benchmark $benchmark
       * @property CI_Calendar $calendar
       * @property CI_Cart $cart
       * @property CI_Config $config
       * @property CI_Controller $controller
       * @property CI_Email $email
       * @property CI_Encrypt $encrypt
       * @property CI_Exceptions $exceptions
       * @property CI_Form_validation $form_validation
       * @property CI_Ftp $ftp
       * @property CI_Hooks $hooks
       * @property CI_Image_lib $image_lib
       * @property CI_Input $input
       * @property CI_Language $language
       * @property CI_Loader $load
       * @property CI_Log $log
       * @property CI_Model $model
       * @property CI_Output $output
       * @property CI_Pagination $pagination
       * @property CI_Parser $parser
       * @property CI_Profiler $profiler
       * @property CI_Router $router
       * @property CI_Session $session
       * @property CI_Sha1 $sha1
       * @property CI_Table $table
       * @property CI_Trackback $trackback
       * @property CI_Typography $typography
       * @property CI_Unit_test $unit_test
       * @property CI_Upload $upload
       * @property CI_URI $uri
       * @property CI_User_agent $user_agent
       * @property CI_Validation $validation
       * @property CI_Xmlrpc $xmlrpc
       * @property CI_Xmlrpcs $xmlrpcs
       * @property CI_Zip $zip
       */

       class CI_Controller {};

       /**
       * @property CI_DB_active_record $db
       * @property CI_DB_forge $dbforge
       * @property CI_Config $config
       * @property CI_Loader $load
       * @property CI_Session $session
       */

       class CI_Model {};


   ?>
   ```
4. Goto

   - Tools
   - plugins
   - Installed

     1. **Uninstall** - PHP CakePHP Framework (Option on Uninstall `restart IDE later`)
     2. **Deactivate** - PHP CI Framework Repositary (Option on Uninstall `restart IDE later`)

---

All fine. As simple go to your controller type `$this->load->` you can see the suggestions Like below image

[image: 01]

Answer (score 3):

please note CI_DB_active_record change in codeigniter 3.

put

```
@property CI_DB_query_builder $db
```

instead of

```
@property CI_DB_active_record $db
```