# How to integrate Codeigniter 3 framework with netbeans 8 or any version completly

Tags: codeigniter, netbeans, codeigniter-3, netbeans-8, codeigniter-hmvc

When using [Project Kenai](https://kenai.com/projects/nbphpci/pages/Home) works only on netbeans 7.*.

So we can use [nb-ci-plugin](https://github.com/nbphpcouncil/nb-ci-plugin/releases) by nbphpcouncil for the framework support in netbeans.

Even when using [nb-ci-plugin](https://github.com/nbphpcouncil/nb-ci-plugin/releases) there is no auto-completion for the codeigniter HMVC.

All the stack overflow question and answer were for just the codeigniter, but im using HMVC extension. No proper answers given for codigniter with HMVC.

question i refered

- [NetBeans 8.0 PHP CodeIgniter Framework support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528784/netbeans-8-0-php-codeigniter-framework-support) -not working in nb-8
- [How to integrate codeIgniter with netbeans fully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308604/how-to-integrate-codeigniter-with-netbeans-fully) -not available for HMVC
- [YavorK/netbeans_codeigniter_hmvc_autocomplete](https://github.com/YavorK/netbeans_codeigniter_hmvc_autocomplete) -not working in nb-8

i refered lots of question and answers but noithing worked.
please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best netbeans plugin to use for codeigniter framework is [nb-ci-plugin](https://github.com/nbphpcouncil/nb-ci-plugin/releases).

When using [nb-ci-plugin](https://github.com/nbphpcouncil/nb-ci-plugin/releases) choose the correct plugin build for the respective netbeans version.

steps to install this plugin is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38407526/5695035) - be sure to choose the correct plugin build/version

and for the auto-complete for CI-HMVC just add

**[YavorK/netbeans_codeigniter_hmvc_autocomplete](https://github.com/YavorK/netbeans_codeigniter_hmvc_autocomplete)**

**contents** leaving the `<?php ?>` tag and add it into the file **__ci_auto_complete__.php** in the netbeans  from **nbproject folder** located in the root of your CI project

[image: add auto-complete for codeigniter HMVC in netbeans 8]

To enable auto-complete for your own **Controller** or **Model** just add it under

```
"/**"
```

for example add a line
`* @property Users $users` 
to include your **Users** module **controller**.

And
`* @property Mdl_users $mdl_users` for your **Mdl_users**  **model**

for autocomplete when typing `$this->users->` use  ↑ (up arrow) to select from the methods of Users

Comment: What else does https://github.com/nbphpcouncil/nb-ci-plugin/releases do though? The repo has no documentation...

Answer (score 0):

After installing the plugins and providing base files in NetBeans (Tools->Options->PHP->CodeIgniter->BaseFiles).

I just copied the codeigniter zip content into the php project in netbeans.[folder structure of codeigniter inside php project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEYpG.png) after that, right click on the project and run so you will see your default navigator with the welcome page from CodeIgniter.