# Convice IDE that variable contains reference to class?

Tags: php, codeigniter, autocomplete, phpstorm, phpdoc

I am using CodeIgniter and have my own classes that I bounce around.

One in particular is a class that gets instantiated from my models, well actually a class that extends this does. It starts off as below,

```
/**
 * @var CI_Controller
 */
protected static $ci;
/**
 * @var CI_DB_active_record
 */
protected static $db;
/**
 * @var Module_Model
 */
protected static $model;

protected $dateModified = null;
protected $dateDeleted = null;
protected $dateCreated = null;

/**
 * @param stdClass $data
 */
public function __construct(stdClass $data) {

    self::$ci =& get_instance();
    self::$db = self::$ci->db;
    self::$model = self::$ci->{self::$model};

    $this->{self::$model->primaryKey} = $data->{self::$model->primaryKey};
    $this->dateModified = (self::$model->dateModified === false ? null : $data->{self::$model->dateModified});
    $this->dateDeleted = (self::$model->softDelete === false ? null : $data->{self::$model->softDelete});
    $this->dateCreated = (self::$model->dateCreated === false ? null : $data->{self::$model->dateCreated});
}
```

Which works fine, in the class that extends this I simply set the constructor to be:

```
public function __construct(stdClass $data) {

    parent::$model = 'properties';

    parent::__construct($data);
}
```

Which is where the line `self::$model = self::$ci->{self::$model};` comes in.

It tells the class what model created is so it can access the model.

This all works great, but the issue I am having is with autocomplete.

Until the above listed line autocomplete works when calling `self::$model->...` it works based off the `Module_Model` class (which is a class all my models extend off) due to this docblock:

```
/**
 * @var Module_Model
 */
```

Now obviously no IDE is going to be smart enough to understand how Code Igniter works, and so I don't expect it to be able to autocomplete based off the model I have specified.

But, I would like it to be able to still autocomplete based off the `Module_Model` class.

Is there anyway (preferably through docblocks) to convince an IDE that `self::$model` still contains a reference to `Module_Model`?

If it matters I am using PHPStorm as my IDE which understands PHPdoc.

Answer (score 0):

You set the PHP include path in PHPStorm, follow [these instructions](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/configuring-include-paths.html).

Then, you may be able to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308604/how-to-integrate-codeigniter-with-netbeans-fully/) to help you (it is for NetBeans).