# CodeIgniter support on netbeans 8.0

Tags: codeigniter, plugins, netbeans-8

I am new in codeIgniter and trying to do the project in netbeans 8.0. The problem is, I can't download the plugin for codeigniter support. It shows some error like

```
"Some plugins require plugin PHP Annotation API to be installed."
```

I checked here for a solution and got this - "http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/184716/"

but the thing which I need is this - "http://alielwafdy.wordpress.com/2012/07/28/codeigniter-support-in-netbeans/".

this supports only up to netbeans 7.3.1

what should I do for netbeans 8.0. Please help

I already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308604/how-to-integrate-codeigniter-with-netbeans-fully). But it is of `Netbeans Version - 7`. I am asking this question to find if there is an option in `Netbeans 8`, **So this is not a duplicate**

Comment: @CaryBondoc, not think so..see the date of accepted answer. There were no good answe at the time when I ask this question. Please check while marking as duplicate.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to integrate codeIgniter with netbeans fully](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308604/how-to-integrate-codeigniter-with-netbeans-fully)

Comment: @Pran, Read the qquestion fully and mark it as duplicate. The version specified in two questions are different. I clearly mentioned that it is for version 8. And you mark the duplicate as `netbeans 7`

Comment: @Arun those tricks are also applicable for Netbeans-8.x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Still there is no direct plugin available even though you can use auto complete class which will helps you for auto complete words.

1. copy the php code from http://blog.bobbyallen.me/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/netbeans_autocomplete_codeigniter.txt
2. save the file into your CodeIgniter Project’s NetBeans folder (in the root, so in the same folder as project.properties and project.xml)
3. If you have NetBeans currently open you’ll need to restart it for the changes to take effect!

Comment: So in which name I have to save the file in the root?? Is there a particular file name? or I have to append this code to some other files?

Comment: I have a problem with `news` controller and its model `Newsmodel`. i.e `$this->Newsmodel->` does not popup auto complete fro its methods.

Answer (score 8):

Alternate way,

- Create folder "CI_Auto_Complete" in outside the project. (ie. like anther project)
- place a php file called "CI_AUTO_COMPLETE.php",
- copy and paste the code from http://blog.bobbyallen.me/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/netbeans_autocomplete_codeigniter.txt
- Add "CI_Auto_Complete" folder to the include path.
- Right on click pjt --> properties --> include path --> Add folder.

Comment: From where i get the include path option?

Comment: It worked for me, but I still cant have autocomplete for my own model. Is there a way to get it?