# php code completion in Netbeans for Codeigniter not available in view

Tags: codeigniter, view, netbeans-8, code-completion

I use Netbeans 8.2 for PHP development, and was able to include code completion for Codeigniter framework.

In the controller and models - which in Codeigniter are oop - the code completion works fine.

In the views, which in Codeigniter are always written in procedural style, code completion is not available.

Here is a simple example controller (taken from CI's homepage)

```
<?php
class News extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('news_model'); # from DB
    }

    public function index()
    {
            $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
            $this->load->view('show_news',$data);
    }
}
```

In the according view, $data['news'] is accessible by the variable "$news". But when I type "$news" I do not have  completion support.

Ideas?

Comment: Just wanted to answer the 1st answer, but it disappeared...

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

you are not passing `$data` to the view :

```
public function index()
{
        $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
        $this->load->view('show_news',$data);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately I only missed to write the $data argument here. I have it in my code, but completion does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans doesn't understand CI out of the box (I believe there are some plugins/modifications you can make so it does).

[How to integrate codeIgniter with netbeans fully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308604/how-to-integrate-codeigniter-with-netbeans-fully)

As such, auto complete functionality won't work and if it did, it would be limited and probably wouldn't understand the view syntax is just the a variable form of the key from an array (that's some AI stuff right there).

Comment: I already had achieved to integrate the CI specific code completion. I only get caught on the view issue...

Comment: well then the latter part of my answer is of particular note